# Stacked UIButtons are squashed

Tags: ios, uibutton

First of all I'm fairly new to iOS design... I can't figure how to fix my current layout:

[image]

As you can see the buttons on the second row are slightly squashed... How to fix that? Here's my XCode scene:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After trying ImageView.ContentMode:

[image]

ASPECT FIT:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the image's **content mode** to **aspect fill**.

Programmatically:

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.fill
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.fill
button.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

...or in storyboard, you need to set *Content Mode* to *Aspect Fill* (make sure *Clips To Bounds* is checked)

[image: setting content mode]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer... it's actually a button, will it work the same way?

Comment: Nope, I just tried that... it was already set as aspect fill, I just checked clip to bounds, but it is still not working.

Comment: @eestein do you have a reference to the UIButton in your view's code?

Comment: Yes, I do have it :)

Comment: @eestein if you do, then you can use `button.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill` and see if that works.

Comment: Hi, apparently that worked, but now the image is cut. It looks like it's not stretched anymore, but it is cut. Please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: Maybe the second StackView is of a shorter height than the first one?

Comment: It does work, but again, the size is smaller. I think the issue is related to the second stack view being shorter than the first one. Please check the updated question again.

Comment: I updated my answer, I think aspect fill should work if you set the button's content mode to fill.

Comment: LMK if that helped, ultimately you just want to experiment with difference content modes and constraints for your button. Without any code, it's hard to understand where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't do the trick. I think the problem is related to the bottom stackview being squashed not the actual buttons. There is no code, It's all being done with Storyboard. Is there any bit of the Storyboard I can take a screenshot to show you?

Comment: I fixed it by adjusting the external stack view to fill equally :) thanks

Comment: @eestein alright awesome, I highly recommend not relying on storyboard so much. Doing things programmatically is cumbersome at first, but it is very worth it so you can fix bugs faster and get better help. Cheers!